# Capture output of a command ran in terminal in a variable

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to capture all the data that I get from a python script that I run into a variable. I took a few inputs from the user within the script and I want to capture everything from start till the end.

It is almost similar to this : [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But again this uses the subprocess within the script to get an output.

What I want is something like this:

when i run ls -l in the terminal, I want my script to capture the ouput of ls -l

If i write :

`p2 = subprocess.Popen('ls' ,'-l',stdout= subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0])`

within my script, that will execute the script twice.

The expected output is to capture all the data when i run ls -l in the terminal to be captured in p2.

Comment: when you say "that will execute the script twice." you mean "that will execute ls -l a second time and I don't want that", right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid all the hassle of using `subprocess.Popen()` explicitly, just go for `os.popen("command").read()` - it runs the former under the hood, and in my case the result of `p2 = os.popen("ls -l").read()` looks just right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pexpect` to easily open a PTY and log everything it shows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pexpect
import io

print("-- Running the program")
p = pexpect.spawn("./foo.py")
p.logfile_read = io.BytesIO()
p.interact();

print("-- Program exited. Here is the log:")
log = p.logfile_read.getvalue().decode("utf-8")
print(log)
```

Here's a `foo.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
name=input("Enter name: ")
print("Hello " + name)
```

Here's what happens when you run it from a terminal:

```
$ ./foo.py
Enter name: World
Hello World
```

And here's what happens when you run it from the logging script:

```
$ ./log.py
-- Running the program
Enter name: World
Hello World
-- Program exited. Here is the log:
Enter name: World
Hello World
```

Comment: That is interesting. I am also using arguments with the script. It keeps changing the way the user wants a certain thing done. How can I take that into consideration using pexpect?

Comment: You can pass a list `args=['-a', '-b']` to `spawn`

Comment: I am using argparse for arguments in my scripts. Some of the arguments does not have a value and some does. How will args list in spawn change for args with values?

Comment: It's up to you to know which arguments your program expects. First figure out how to invoke it manually on a command line, then you can try to invoke it via pexpect.

Comment: So I am assuming the log script and the actual script you want to log should be different. I wanted a snapshot of what foo.py does within foo.py itself. Tl;dr I am recording what the script is doing inside a variable within foo.py itself.

Comment: In that case you could just write the script so that any time you read or write something, it's also added to a log

Comment: That is what I want and I am not sure how will I be able to do that. Still a novice in Python:)